# How to write efficient javascript/jQuery code involving loops and string concat?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using kendo grid's `onDataBound` event to do something.  Here's my jQuery code:

```
console.time('withoutnot');
jQuery(e.sender.dataSource._data).each(function (i, v) {
     if (v.IsReadonly) {
         e.sender.wrapper.find("tr[data-uid='" + v.uid + "'] .k-button")
                .each(function (i, j) {
                    if (!jQuery(this).hasClass('k-grid-edit') && !jQuery(this).hasClass('k-grid-Desc')) {
                        jQuery(this).addClass('k-state-disabled').prop('disabled', true)
                                .prop('title', 'Readonly.');
                    }
                });
    }
});
console.timeEnd('withoutnot');
```

`onDataBound` event gets raised once the grid has completed data-load from serverside.

My problem is that, because of 400 rows in the grid (without paging), it takes around `355ms` to `378ms`, which is still slower for me, because it causes visible performance lag in the grids load(readonly button effect).

How can I improve this code snippet even more? or is it the best I can go for?

NOTE: using native `for` or jQuerys `:not` (instead of those if conditions), proved disaster to me, load time scaled to `460ms` to `550ms`.

I am using `jQuery 1.7.1`

Comment: Out of curiousity how were you writing the `:not` as I'd expect it to be even with your filter and more elegant

Comment: like this : `e.sender.wrapper.find("tr[data-uid='" + v.uid + "'] .k-button:not(.k-grid-edit,.k-grid-Desc )")`. This would save me the need of that inner if condition.But Pseudo selectors are superbly slow

Answer (score 4):

I found out solution to my problem. so basically this is what I learnt

1. use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set of similar items instead of explicit if condition
2. use cached variables i.e. `var $this = $(this);`
3. use [methods chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)
4. and if same methods are to be used multiple times, try using it like:

   ```
   .prop({ disabled: true, title: 'Readonly.' });
   ```

   instead of call `.prop` (or any other) multiple times.
5. try to scope restrict the context of your selector as far as you can, i.e.

   ```
   jQuery("tr[data-uid='" + v.uid + "'] .k-button", e.sender.wrapper)
   ```

so here's my final query:

```
jQuery(e.sender.dataSource._data).each(function (i, v) {
   if (v.IsReadonly) {
      jQuery("tr[data-uid='" + v.uid + "'] .k-button", e.sender.wrapper)
       .filter(function (i) {
          var $this = jQuery(this);
          return !($this.hasClass('k-grid-edit') || $this.hasClass('k-grid-Desc'));
        })
        .addClass('k-state-disabled')
        .prop({ disabled: true, title: 'Readonly.' });
   }
});
```

and this query took `267ms` - `296ms` (for 10 iterations)

-- I hope there can still be something even more faster like getting rid of that parent `.each` loop